# css position for pseudo class in checkbox not working

Tags: css, less, frontend

I need to create a tick in a checkbox using CSS and not an image.

I can see the green '✔' showing up correctly. but the top and left in css is just not working the tick sign is always stuck at the upper left corner  at the checkbox and I want it at the middle. Why is the content and color property working but left and top not working?

Comment: Would you mind linking to a jsfiddle with your example? - thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sksm0tcc/ as you can see the color is working bug top left is has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top and left doesn't work with static element, you need to specify a relative, fixed or absolute position in order to use these property. You can try this :

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .icon:after, ._checked input[type=checkbox] ~ .icon :after {
    background-position: 0 -800px;
    content: '✔';
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 15px;
    left: 250px;
    color: green;
    position: relative;
}
```

A full code :

```css
input[type=checkbox]:focus+.icon {
  background-position: 0 -822px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.icon,
._checked input[type=checkbox]~.icon {
  background-position: 0 -856px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.icon:after,
._checked input[type=checkbox]~.icon :after {
  background-position: 0 -800px;
  content: '✔';
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-12px;
  color: green;
  position:relative;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)+div.validationsContainer~.icon {
  background-position: 0 -890px;
}

,
input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover+label,
input[type=checkbox]:checked:focus+label {
  background-position: 0 15.3%;
}

&.hasError .icon {
  background-position: 0 -890px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" required="required" name="terms" id="termsAgree" auto-required="true">
<span class="icon"></span>
```